# Is there a way to limit the number of async writeFile operations in node.js and maintain a FIFO queue?

Tags: node.js

I get a number of `EMFILE,open <filename>` errors when writing to a file. I take the pre cause of checking that the parent directory exists before trying to write the actual file, but after a point I get too many of those errors.

Is there a way to limit the number of async writeFile operations and maintain a FIFO queue ?

All my "fs.writeFile" calls are from the same method, so it would be easy to slip something in there that ensures that only a certain number of async calls are done at a time.

Any suggestions how to implement this ?

Comment: The async library can do this for you.  Or it's not particularly difficult to code yourself.  Did you try?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm working on it right now, but it seems a little complicated because if the readstream that I am reading from reads events faster than I can write, then the queue size increases and uses up a lot more memory (which is already precious), so I'm trying to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: The usual solution to that problem is to move some control upstream so the writers can be told to stop writing until they get called back.  I don't know streams very well myself, but I think they have this capability built in.